# Correctly position responsive image caption?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am hoping someone can help me with a positioning problem I am having.

I am trying to code up an image caption. Normally, I would have no problems with this... however, I am trying to position a caption on the right hand side, half way down the image.

I have implemented it [here](http://goo.gl/JAUGwD) (sort of lol). However, I am using a tonne of media queries to stop the caption getting chopped off on the right hand side.

I can't help but think there must be a cleaner, more efficient way of doing this... can anyone help me please? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have relative positioning for the image's parent element, you can absolute position the caption, and use a bottom percentage to position correctly.

```
.img-wrap {
  position:relative;
}

.caption {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:15%;
  right:0;
  padding:0.5em;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpa1n6ng/2/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpa1n6ng/2/show/)

Comment: Thanks so much, your demo is perfect and just what I was looking for. It doesn't seem to be working for me though so I will keep fiddling :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I got it to work in the end! Yay, thanks again!!